# Privileges page has broken alignment

Tags: bug, status-norepro, design, site-faq

[This page](https://askubuntu.com/privileges/new-user) has some messed up alignment in the right sidebar.

Here's what it should look like,

[image]

But when you click on the link it breaks.

[image]

This doesn't seem to be an issue on other StackExchange sites like StackOverflow.

Comment: I get this too. Firefox 7.0.1 in Ubuntu 11.10

Comment: I also get this in Firefox 6 on Windows 7. Looks like the long text is causing some layout issues.

Comment: Hmm, was it fixed? I'm not seeing it anymore on Chrome or Firefox on Ubuntu 11.10. I had tested it earlier on Windows 7.

Comment: Oh, maybe not. I'm still seeing it on Chrome on OS X.

Comment: I am not seeing this problem in Chromium (`chromium-browser` `15.0.874.106~r107270-0ubuntu0.11.10.1`) on Lubuntu 11.10 (1366x768 res, maximized), nor with Firefox 7.0.1 (`firefox` `7.0.1+build1+nobinonly-0ubuntu2`) on the same system.

Comment: I still get this with Firefox 10.0 in Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: @N.N. Interesting. It's actually fixed for me. It appears that the font is different than the one in the screenshot I posted. Judging from the CSS, it looks like the font is Ubuntu Beta. Is that what you see?

Comment: @root45 I was wrong, it is actually fixed (see my answer). My misstake was to not disable the minimum font site which I had set to 13 and with it the line got too long.

Answer (score 3):

This seems fixed. The following shows how it looks for me in Firefox and Chromium.

Firefox 10.0:

[image: Seen in Firefox 10.0]

Chromium 16.0.912.77:

[image: Seen in Chromium 16.0.912.77]

Answer (score 1):

The privileges page has been completely redesigned since 2011.